# how to resolve http code 412 and 200 when I am posting json using swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, alamofire

I am trying to send a very simple dictionary to the json file in my local host using swift (`Alamofire`) 
Here is what I've done :

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["name" : "Danial"]


        Alamofire.request("http://localhost/testing.json", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters).response { result in
            if result.response?.statusCode != nil {
                 if let status =  (result.response?.statusCode)! as? Int {

                    print("status : \(status)")
                }
            }

        }
```

and inside my testing.json I have the following :

```
{  
   "x":"y"
}
```

and I get the the http status 412 (frequently) and the 200 (without in apperance of the new json in the json file) rarely . I am very new to this networking stuff . thus , please dont attack my question as if I must know this simple thing . This has already taken me 2 days to resolve yet i am here :| 
by the way there should be no error in connection as my get protocol seems to be working fine

Comment: what do you mean by "without in apperance of the new json in the json file" ? You get a success response but no data retrieved ? Also a best practice when you provide data as an API is to use get (not post), but that doesn't really matter here.

Comment: You need to learn what is error HTTP 412, what it means, and why you get it. It could be totally related to your server part, an error you are wrongly returning, etc.

Comment: @DamienBannerot what I mean by that is that although it seems that the http is successful (200) but still the content i am trying to post wont appear in the json file meaning that file wont change at all .

Comment: Oh it's indeed a post, don't mind my first comment then. As Jeffery mentionned you are requesting on a json file instead of a webservice, have you create a server path and handle the json editing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here are a couple of things I see.

1. When you send a POST to a server, the URL must be to a Web Service or a web app of some kind. Here it appears you are trying to POST to a resource file.  Static resource files will not update automatically.
2. You didn't specify the encoding, so you didn't post JSON (application/json), you posted Form URL Encoded (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Instead of being `{ "name": "Danial" }`, you sent `name=Danial`.

You need to set the encoding to JSON.

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["name" : "Danial"]

Alamofire.request("http://localhost/testing.json",
                  method: HTTPMethod.post,
                  parameters: parameters,
                  encoding: JSONEncoding.default).response { result in
    if result.response?.statusCode != nil {
        if let status =  (result.response?.statusCode)! as? Int {
            print("status : \(status)")
        }
    }
}
```